# iOS iPad how to create a UIPopoverController with UIActionSheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm remaking one of my iPhone apps that uses `UIActionSheet` into an iPad app and **would like to add the action sheet within a** `UIPopoverController`. I know this shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm very new to the whole popover design.  Is there's an example I can take a look at?

Comment: I don't think you need to combine the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744260/uipopover-how-do-i-make-a-popover-with-buttons-like-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add it in Popover view. UIActionSheet is normally wrapped inside Popover view in iPad