# How can we create this custom component?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, custom-view

See the screenshot below:

[image]

How can we create this View in IOS applications? Or is this any built in View?

Comment: this is UIPopovercontroller. For implementation see this http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial.

Comment: [`UIPopverController` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a good starting point for you,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

This is `UIPopoverController`

Check [Developer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this third party controller [Link](https://github.com/sonsongithub/PopupView). It is very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

see simple demo [here](https://github.com/the1pawan/GridView-and-popUpView) uses UIPopoverController

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [WEPopover](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wepopover). I haven't used it but it looks useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything custom in order to use this component.

This is a `UIActionSheet` presented from a `UIPopover`

The small text is the title of the `UIActionSheet` and the red button is the so called destructive button.

See some discussion and examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744260/uipopover-how-do-i-make-a-popover-with-buttons-like-this).